# JavaScript sum of a number

Tags: javascript

I have this number 55555

If we add this single number then the result will be = 25 and then if we add 2 + 5 then the result will be 7.

I want to make it but can't get the result:

What I have done so far:

```
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  // Write the code that goes here.
    string = membershipId.split('');                
    let sum = 0;                               
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {  
        sum += parseInt(string[i],10);         
    }
  
    console.log(sum.split(''));
   
    
  
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

Comment: ...you made `sum` a number, what would `sum.split` even do?

Comment: Its recursion. Call same function until you get number less than 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the function recursive - after the loop, if the sum is 10 or more, call it again:

```js
function createCheckDigit(membershipId) {
  // Write the code that goes here.
    string = membershipId.split('');                
    let sum = 0;                               
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {  
        sum += parseInt(string[i],10);         
    }
    return sum >= 10 ? createCheckDigit(String(sum)) : sum;
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

Or, more concisely:

```js
function createCheckDigit(num) {
  const nextNum = num.split('').reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);
  return nextNum >= 10 ? createCheckDigit(String(nextNum)) : nextNum;
}

console.log(createCheckDigit("55555"));
```

Comment: can you explain this line please: `return sum >= 10 ? createCheckDigit(String(sum)) : sum;`

Comment: why we need to check with `10`

Comment: @creativeartbd If the sum is 10 or more, you need to go through the process again until the result is a single digit (0 to 9), right? So, check if it's `>= 10` to see if it's needed.

Comment: can you give me a resource where I can learn that type of algorithms?

Comment: @creativeartbd All I really added to your algorithm was the recursive check. Just think about how you'd solve it on paper ("If the sum is 10 or more, repeat") and then translate into code. Knowing about concise idiomatic ways to solve it in a particular programming language (like `.reduce` in JS) is nice too, but it's mostly just critical thinking and then translating it into code.